# CakePHP 2 AJAX redirections

Tags: ajax, cakephp, redirect, cakephp-2.0

I'm using AJAX in my web-app stuffs like search but if the user has been logged out, the ajax function return nothing because the redirection (from the action 'search' to the action 'login') has not been handled correctly.

Is it possible to redeclare the method 'redirect' in AppController to render the right action when a redirect hapend in an AJAX call ?

Thank you, 
Sébastien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best bet would be to setup you ajax to call to respond correctly to an invalid response. As it seems to be an important part of your app I would pass a 'loggedin' variable with every ajax request, so the client can tell as soon as the user has been logged out.

**Update**

In the case you want to keep a user logged in, you simply have to put the logged in/cookie check in something like your `AppController::beforeFilter()` that gets run with every request. for example:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
     if($this->Auth->user() {
          // USer is logged in, it's all gravy
     } else {
         // User is not logged in, try to log them in
         $userData = $this->Cookie->read('User');
     if(!empty($userData)) {
              // Function that grabs info from cookie and logs in user
         }
     }
}
```

This way there will be no redirect as the user will be logged in as long as they have a cookie.

Comment: But I don't want that the user have to reconnect himself, I have an automatic loggin function with cookie informations. I want that when the AJAX call is made, that CakePHP check if the user is logged in and auto-reconnect hif if he's not.

Comment: Ok, thank you for this. But know, if a "never-logged-in-user" is in a public page and fire an AJAX event that need a log-in, there will be a redirection to the loggin page in this method (for the non-ajax call). So the AJAX return will be empty (without any error) ; how to not break the method and do a "pseudo-redirection" to have the login page returned to the AJAX call ?

Comment: Well you will know if a user is "never logged in" on the original page doing the ajax request, so you should be able to prevent that from happening in some way. Maybe see the first part of my answer and put something that will react appropriately to the redirect response.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to allow everyone access to the Ajax function:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
  $this->Auth->allow(array('my_ajax_method'));
}
```

And then check the user is authenticated in the method itself:

```
public function my_ajax_method() {

    if (!$this->Auth->user()) {
       //user not authenticated
       $result = "requires auth";
    }
    else {
       // use is authenticated
       // do stuff
       $result = 'result of stuff';
    }

    $this->set(compact('result'));

}
```

You will need to check the result of the ajax call in your javascript and act accordingly.

Comment: This is not possible because much of my AJAX methods are "standard" methods with with a "$this->request->is('Ajax')" condition.

Comment: Thanks, your answer saved my time.